# In Office Apps for Excel 2013 - Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'context'"

Tags: javascript, configurable

I have made an app in Office Apps for Excel 2013. It works fine, but at start up it gives a javascript exception.

> "Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'context'".

After clicking 'continue' on that exception everything works just fine. This application uses its inbuilt App.js and Office.js.
Is there any solution for this? Or is there something i can remove in my code so that it always hits at start up.

Comment: Does the issue occur when you use office.js in SharePoint online or Exchange online?

Comment: Please read the following link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161122.aspx

Comment: It occours when i run my Office 2013 Excel app.

Comment: @Spark please can you mention how did you solve this? I am running in same situation.

Comment: I found where it was occurring and I removed that line in js. But as far as i can remember this problem went automatically after some days when I rebuilt/restarted the app

Comment: @Spark, when you say "I found where it was occurring and I removed that line in js".  Is that in your JS code, or inside of Office.js?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and was able to solve it by removing second Office.js script. This issue will occur if you load Office.js script more than once.
See: [In Office Apps - Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'context'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201860/in-office-apps-cannot-redefine-non-configurable-property-context/39202581#39202581)