# In Office Apps - Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'context'"

Tags: office365, office-addins, office-app

This is similar to [In Office Apps for Excel 2013 - Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'context'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228753/in-office-apps-for-excel-2013-cannot-redefine-non-configurable-property-conte).

However it only happens on IE 11 and Edge.
My use case is followin:
I open outlook or any office application add-in. I run a pop-up for OAuth, on popup close i redirect the iframe to another page.

First time i open the addin and finish OAuth flow everything is working correctly. However when I close the add-in and open it again (this time redirect is done automatically because user is authentication and is recognized by cookie) Office Add-in fails to start, when i restart it manually few times it will open up and work correctly.

Error I'm getting is:  Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'context' in
Office.js (o15apptofilemappingtable.js (11,3563))

Edit: Issue also occurs on Firefox and Chrome, however it is handled more gracefully and add-in doesn't crash, it starts with error logged to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end issue was that there were two Office.js libraries of different version referenced. When older one was removed, issue was gone.

Comment: In my case I had ```import '@microsoft/office-js/dist/office'``` in some files. I had to use that to silence typescript error (`Office is undefined`).